# c++ singleton attempt: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, singleton

I am a c# developper trying to do c++ things and I cannot understand the issue here:

```
namespace myNamespace
{
    class Application
    {
    private:
        Application(void);
        ~Application(void);

        // Not copyable
        Application(const Application&);
        Application& operator= (const Application&);

        static Application _instance; 

        [...]

    public:
        static Application& current(void);
    };
}
```

(this is supposed to be a singleton...)

and this causes the error:
"**error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class myNamespace::Application myNamespace::Application::_instance" (?_instance@Application@myNamespace@@0V12@A)**"

Is it because I am using the class I am declaring in the class declaration?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You only *declare* `_instance` in Application class, you need to *define it* in .cpp file:

```
namespace myNamespace
{
    Application Application::_instance; 
}
```

§ 9.4.2.2

> **The declaration of a static data member in its class definition is not a definition** and may be of an incomplete type other than cv-qualified void. The definition for a static data member shall appear in a namespace scope enclosing the member’s class definition. In the definition at namespace scope, the name of the static data member shall be qualified by its class name using the :: operator.

Comment: My god, it works!!!! thanks a lot. (in the example `myNamespace::Application myNamespace::Application::_instance;` )

Comment: You'll never stop learning. Thank you @billz